# Why does XeO3 not hybridize d orbitals?

Tags: bond, electronic-configuration, noble-gases

Apologies if this is a dumb question. In my chemistry class we are discussing hybridization, and an example that came up for $sp_3$ hybridization was the compound $\ce{XeO3}$.

However, this seems counterintuitive. While the lewis structure of the compound is

[image]

and by inspection we see that there are 4 groups of electrons, the three double bonds and the lone pair which implies $sp_3$, from my understanding, the ability of xenon to form compounds relies solely on the fact that Xenon can use its $d$ orbitals to bond.

Why are the $s$ and $p$ orbitals implicated in the bonding and not the $d$ orbitals?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/67352/about-dative-covalent-bonding-and-expanded-octet-rule

Comment: @Mithoron From the first link you shared, can I basically interpret this as $\text{Xe}$ bonding with $\text{O}$ in a way where xenon sends an electron to oxygen but not vice versa, so the bonding only inolves the s and p orbitals?

Comment: Yes, the bonds can be considered dative. Also there's hardly any involvement of d orbitals in hybrids in *every* compound you'd think of as "hypervalent".

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/167501/bonding-in-hypervalent-molecules

Comment: BTW titles shouldn't have mathjax because of searchability issues.