Why does Iodic acid exist and Iodous acid does not?
Iodous acid would not exist because of the weak 2pπ-5dπ bond between I and O. However, in Iodic acid, won't two such bonds be present between a central iodine and two oxygen atoms? Won't that further cause its stability to decrease? Iodic acid is a very stable oxyacid though, and I cannot understand why.

There is no pπ-dπ in pretty much any compound.

@Mithoron Yep, that is the reason iodous acid does not exist/is highly unstable. What about iodic acid though?

Not really, it's not a problem, just a misconception.

@Mithoron I'm sorry, but I didn't really get what you're trying to say. Could you possibly make an answer and explain the misconception?

Same as here I guess https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/19836/how-can-compounds-like-xeo4-form-tetrahedral-structures-despite-having-double-bo There's no stupid d orbitals involved with p block compounds.

Iodous acid certainly has been detected but never isolated. From Wikipedia - Iodites (including iodous acid) are highly unstable and have been observed but never isolated. They will rapidly disproportionate to molecular Iodine and Iodates. However, they have been detected as intermediates in the conversion between iodide and iodate.

@NilayGhosh Thanks for the answer.
